# Maximum age limit for marriage in Hinduism?

Tags: marriage

What is the maximum age limit for marriage in Hinduism? I am 35 years old can I marry at this age a young girl or Hinduism doesnot permit it should I convert to other religion.

Comment: Besides being a duplicate this portion "should I convert to other religion." is opinion based and hence a candidate for closure too.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can marry as per Hinduism.

This is what Manusmṛti says -

> [Verse 9.94](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201459.html)
>
> त्रिंशद्वर्षो वहेत् कन्यां हृद्यां द्वादशवार्षिकीम् ।
> त्र्यष्टवर्षोऽष्टवर्षां वा धर्मे सीदति सत्वरः ॥ ९४ ॥
>
> > 94. **A man thirty years old shall marry a charming maiden twelve years old; or one twenty four years old, a damsel eight years old; in the
> >     event of his duties suffering, he may do it sooner.**

However, this must be read with the commentary by  Medhātithi’s on the same verse

> **Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):**
>
> What the injunction means is that the maiden married should be so much
> younger than the man;—and not that marriage must be done only at. the
> age stated. Nor is any stress meant to be laid upon the exact number
> of years mentioned; all that is meant is that one should many a girl
> very much younger than himself.

From the same page, The translator Ganganath Jha gives other verses from various scripture.

> **Comparative notes by various authors**
>
> **Mahābhārata (13.41.14)**.— ‘**One who is thirty or twenty-one years old
> shall take a wife sixteen years old, but before she has attained
> puberty.**’
>
> ---
>
> **Viṣṇupurāṇa** (Vīramitrodaya-Saṃskāra, p. 766).—‘**A man shall select a
> wife whose age is one-third of his own.**’
>
> ---
>
> **Āpastamba** (Do., p. 767).—**‘A man thirty-years old shall take a wife ten
> years old, before she has attained puberty;** and one twenty-one years
> old, a girl seven years old.’
>
> ---
>
> **Āśvalāyana** (Do.).—‘A maiden seven years old is called Śaiśavī; a man
> eighteen years of age shall marry her; a maiden eight years old is
> called Gaurī, conducive to richness of sons and grandsons; and she
> shall be married by a man twenty-five years old; a girl nine years old
> is called Rohiṇī conducive to richness of wealth; a wise man shall wed
> her for the accomplishment of all his desires; a girl over ten years
> age, until she has her courses, is called Gāndhārī; and she shall be
> married by a man desirous of living long.’

So, certainly, at 35 years of age, you may marry a desirable "young girl", as per scriptures. However, you must conform the above guidelines with the law of the land, and your elders and gurus.